# What is the default List implementation in Jaxb2, and how do I change it?

Tags: java, list, jaxb, jaxb2

Does anyone know what the default implementation is for List instances in JaxB2?

Is there a way to change the implementation, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default List implementation in JAXB 2 is java.util.ArrayList.  When generating your model from an XML schema you can set the `collectionType` in an external bindings file to choose an alternate implementation:

```
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="customer.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='customer']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='phone-number']">
            <jxb:property collectionType="java.util.LinkedList"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-choosing-list-implementation.html

Comment: What if you're not generating your model from an XML schema?  It looks like from that article you linked that the only way to specify it with only Java code (no XJC, whatever that is) is through specifying the type of the list in the variable (i.e. private LinkedList<XmlType> list).

Comment: If you initialize you list field then your JAXB impl will use it:  List foo = new LinkedList();.

Comment: I've had JaxB2 place null lists in the fields if the element isn't there - will it respect the field being non-null if the child elements aren't there (in the XML that I'm mapping, it's a 0-N relationship)?